# Is Apache Cordova built on NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, cordova

Is there any NodeJS in Apache Cordova? I'm aware of that you can install Cordova CLI using npm but this just means that Cordova is packaged using npm as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no NodeJS used in Cordova. Cordova apps are ran as client application on web browser and thus they require nothing like NodeJS.

You are though right about the npm part as Cordova (and some submodules) is packaged as npm module for easy deployment.

Please also note that the source code for different projects of Apache Cordova can be found on their own [home page](https://cordova.apache.org/).

Comment: Thank you @sanfor.
Just needed clarification as my company's CTO apparently mention there is a node element in it and it got me confused as I have known there isn't. Just needed clarification. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Command Line of Cordova is built on top of Node JS. That is explicitely mentioned [here](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/releases/2013/07/23/cordova-3.html#new_command_line_tooling). Also on npm the requirements clearly state that Node JS is necessary ([requirements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova)).

Now as far as I know only the CLI is implemented using Node JS, the rest of it maybe doesnt require Node JS, but that I dont know.

Edit: Also as mentioned by others, Cordova apps are NOT packaged with Node JS but rather with a Web-view. The CLI and the built app are two completely different and independent things.